# Can't send basic email with javamail

Tags: java, maven, email, localhost, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send the most basic e-mail using javamail. I basically copy pasted the code given here but still get an exception: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

I've searched for similar errors but can't find an answer.

Code:

```
package main.java;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Email {

/*
 * This class sends an email to a specified email address
 */
private final String recipient = "foo@baz.com";
private final String sender = "baz@foo.com";
private Properties properties = null;
private Session session = null;

public Email() {

    properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

}

public void send() {

    try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(recipient));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
}

}
```

I also added the following dependencies in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on your machine? If not, replace "localhost" with the host name of your mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail API is trying to contact a mail server via SMTP to send the mail. You configured it to use the mail server on localhost, i.e. the same machine the code is running on. The error "connection refused" means that nothing is listening on the standard SMTP port (25)

My guess is that no mail server is running on that machine. Find out which server you want to use (or which one you are allowed to use) and use that for the SMTP host configuration.

Comment: Do you have any mail servers to recommend? I see gmail can be used but are there any better options?

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#incservers) has answers to many of your current and future questions, including sample code.